# (SOLVED) Nvidia drivers for GF 800M on Lenovo C460 All-in-One?

Tags: release-loki, boot, graphic-drivers, nvidia

Would like to test if my system would run on nvidia graphics card.

Here is the hardware:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem Lenovo 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo GeForce 800M
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Unfortunately, additional drivers detect only the intel hardware:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
intel-microcode
```

Somewhere on this site, for GF800 series, it was recommended to install the nvidia-358 version.

I know I can try to install them this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
```

but...

I know people had black screen problems after install. I would like to know what to do, to be able to eventually get back to current, free driver, if something fails.

**I dont have any grub menu while loading. It is a single-boot machine.**

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I risked installing the nvidia drivers...And it paid off :D

While adding nvidia ppa I've noticed, that for GF8** series it is recommended to install the 340 driver version. Tried the latest and 358, but both were not found. Tried 340 and it got installed without any errors.
I rebooted without any blacklisting of other drivers and without messing with grub parameters. No black screen, Elementary logo stayed on its place, desktop showed up.
I guess reading information is still a good practice.

inxi output:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.59hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 800M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.106 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

lspci output:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GeForce 800M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Even my Hardware Sensors Indicator shows temp for the GF card.

[image]

Ladies & Gentleman, case closed :D